# Apache configuration FollowSymlinks- Apply to php scripts?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, symbolic-link

I have Options set to none for my webroot directory. I also have a symmlink /var/coderoot -> /var/webroot/coderoot

In the php script I can do include("/var/coderoot/file"); and it works fine. Regardless of the option (yes I save and restart apache.) Does follow symlinks only apply to symlinks used in a certain way? Is there a performance loss using the include with a symmlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache httpd [option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) `FollowSymLinks` is only valid for Apache httpd and modifies only the web server's behavior. PHP (whether implemented as an Apache module or through CGI/FastCGI) does not know about this option at all.

From a pure technical standpoint, resolving the symbolic link and then opening the target file is a little more complicated than opening the target file directly but in practice you won't see a difference.